# Firebase(firestore) update data with array

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

What I should do to change the status value in the document specified in the desired collection groups.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't update a single property on a specific item in the array. You will have to:

1. Read the entire document into you application code.
2. Get the current value of the `data` array from the document.
3. Update item `0` in the `data` array in the application code.
4. Write the entire `data` array back to the database.